# 2016 Jeep Compass Transmission Issue- cannot be replicated by dealership?

Tags: automatic-transmission, jeep, compass

I purchased a certified pre-owned 2016 Jeep Compass back in Dec. 2017 from a large Jeep dealership. In April 2018, while on a 3 hour trip, the car would not accelerate past 30mph on an expressway-terrifying!. We took the car to the dealership and they replaced with a refurbished transmission. Once and a while it would feel glitchy but nothing often enough to worry about (I thought). About 6 months ago the glitches became more frequent and I took it back to the dealership and they flushed the transmission, costing me around $300.  It seemed to remedy the situation temporarily. Last week I was driving and was stopped at a light. When the light turned green, I hit the gas and the car wouldn't go. I shut it off and turned it back on and it went- but it was frightening! It also started bucking again after driving for a few minutes or accelerating. We took it in to the mechanic and they informed us that they were unable to replicate any issues when test driving it for 8 miles. They also mentioned that the computer did not give an error code. The manager offered to drive it to his home to see if the issue would replicate.

What are my option here? This is the 3rd time I have taken it in for transmission issues. It definitely has a problem and these transmissions in this model are known to be problematic (our personal mechanic mentioned it when we dropped it off for a brake job). The car is still under its power train warranty until November, so of course I would like to get this taken care of sooner than later. Is it possible that the dealership could lie?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, sometimes problems don't present themselves when we want/need them to. If the shop you took it to is willing to drive the vehicle longer than the 8 miles in an attempt to recreate the issue, you have to trust they are doing everything they can to make it happen. You have to decide for yourself if this is something you want to have happen (them driving your vehicle), whether you want to take it somewhere else to have it looked at (2nd opinion), live with what you have, or possibly get rid of it all together.

Seeing as how the manager hasn't outright said you are making things up and is willing to drive it to replicate, it sounds like they are willing to at least try. When a vehicle is under warranty, it isn't like the dealership has to pay for this. They get reimbursed by the warranty company, whether that's Jeep/Chrysler/Fiat or 3rd party for the work. They are not out any money for doing the warranty work, so they really have no reason to lie about anything.

Anyways, bottom line here is, it really comes down to what you want to do. We won't be able to help you in that department.